# Draw time of the current frame in seconds with just 2 digits after point

Tags: ffmpeg

I can’t find the way to draw time of the current frame in seconds with just 2 digits after point.
I tried “drawtext”, and it does well, however it gives or int seconds, or float with many digits =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `eif` function in drawtext. This can be used to compute a value of an expression and print it as integer of specified number of digits. It is used once for each of hours, minutes, seconds and centiseconds.

`text='%{eif\:t/3600\:d\:2}\:%{eif\:mod(t/60\,60)\:d\:2}\:%{eif\:mod(t\,60)\:d\:2}\:%{eif\:100*mod(t\,1)\:d\:2}'`

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontsize=60:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{eif\:mod(t\,60)\:d\:2}\.%{eif\:100*mod(t\,1)\:d\:2}':x=(w-text_w):y=(h-text_h)" output.mp4

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the answer from `Gyan`:

```
text='%{pts\:gmtime\:0\:%T}.%{eif\:100*mod(t\,1)\:d\:2}'
```

I've no idea if it's any less cpu intensive or not but it seems to get the job done.

Basically `%T` gives us HH:MM:SS and the `eif` function is from @Gyan above.

Note:
The only way I achieved this before finding Gyan's code above, was to change the video's frames per second, very expensive!