# ffmpeg add text every second with enable between filter

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -y -i public/media/vid1.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='1':x=w-tw-50:y=50:fontcolor=black:fontsize=380:enable='between(t,1,2)',drawtext=text='2':x=w-tw-50:y=50:fontcolor=black:fontsize=380:enable='between(t,0,1)'" -codec:a copy public/media/vid1-1.mp4
```

I want to add a number every second in a video. I googled and the syntax should like the above. However, only the text within `between(t,0,1)` can be shown and the value is keeping shown for the whole video duration. But I expected it should only show one second.

I expected `between(t,1,2)` can show the text from 00:00:01-00:00:02. However, it never show.

Answer (score 0):

Your command works for me, in ffmpeg 5.1.2. I get the two number displayed. Which version are you using ?

Also, you can use the `enable=lt(mod(t\,X)\,1)` to make the text appear for 1 second, every X seconds

As for the text itself, if you want to print numbers, you may use the `eif` function, to evaluate expressions, like in this example [Draw time of the current frame in seconds with just 2 digits after point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221082/draw-time-of-the-current-frame-in-seconds-with-just-2-digits-after-point)

Comment: i am also using ffmpeg 5.12 in mac

Comment: lastly i found the problem is the video source..
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -t 5 -i public/media/vid1.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 18  -pix_fmt yuv420p public/media/vid1.mp4
i used this script to generate the origin video and i found if i use another video the text can be added